# Class Not Found Eception at run time IN JAVA file in Linux (In MAT LAB Integration)

Tags: java, matlab

i have created JAVA_PACKAGE from MAT LAB and integrate it in Java program. on windows it is running perfectly but when i tried to run it on another system with Ubuntu OS it is giving bellow error..

```
arcadian@arcadian-desktop:~/makesqr/for_testing$ javac -classpath "/home/arcadian/Documents/MATLAB_Runtime_Install/v85/toolbox/javabuilder/jar/javabuilder.jar":\makesqr.jar \getmagic.java
arcadian@arcadian-desktop:~/makesqr/for_testing$ java -classpath .:"/home/arcadian/Documents/MATLAB_Runtime_Install/v85/toolbox/javabuilder/jar/javabuilder.jar":.\makesqr.jar getmagic 5
Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
finnaly: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: makesqr/Class1
at getmagic.main(getmagic.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: makesqr.Class1
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

my Java file code is here ..

```
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.*;
import makesqr.*;

class getmagic
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  MWNumericArray n = null;
  Object[] result = null;
  Class1 theMagic = null;

  if (args.length == 0)
  {
    System.out.println("Error: must input a positive integer");
    return;
  }

  try
  {
       try
      {
         n = new MWNumericArray(Double.valueOf(args[0]),
                                      MWClassID.DOUBLE);

         theMagic = new Class1();

         result = theMagic.makesqr(1, n);
        System.out.println(result[0]);
        }
        catch(MWException e)
        {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
  }
  catch (Error e)
  {
     System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
  }
  finally
  {
 System.out.println("finnaly: " );
     MWArray.disposeArray(n);
     MWArray.disposeArray(result);
     theMagic.dispose();
  }
}
}
```

Comment: It seems like it can't find the makesqr import. Be sure to add all the required libraries when you port it to another OS.

Comment: yes it is not able to find Class1.. Which is in makesqr.jar . but from my side i have included everything but error remains same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a problem with your classpath.  Is "makesqr.jar" in the ~/makesqr/for_testing folder?  If so, could you try this:

arcadian@arcadian-desktop:~/makesqr/for_testing$ javac -classpath "/home/arcadian/Documents/MATLAB_Runtime_Install/v85/toolbox/javabuilder/jar/javabuilder.jar":makesqr.jar getmagic.java
arcadian@arcadian-desktop:~/makesqr/for_testing$ java -classpath .:"/home/arcadian/Documents/MATLAB_Runtime_Install/v85/toolbox/javabuilder/jar/javabuilder.jar":makesqr.jar getmagic 5

I think the problem is that you've used \ as a path separator, which works in Windows but is different in Linux.

Comment: 'arcadian@arcadian-desktop:~/makesqr/for_testing$ java -classpath .:"/home/arcadian/Documents/MATLAB_Runtime_Install/v85/toolbox/javabuilder/jar/javabuilder.jar":makesqr.jar getmagic 5
Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
finnaly: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at getmagic.main(getmagic.java:44)
'                   This is the result.

Comment: Fantastic, then it looks like that fixed the classpath issue!
The NPE will be a problem in your code, and it's hard to say exactly what without all the code.  At a guess, I'd suggest the MWNumericArray constructor threw an exception, causing the "finally" block to run before "theMagic" was initialised, which then caused at null pointer at 44 when it tries to call the dispose method, which swallows the original exception.

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace?  Sticking a quick null check around line 44 is likely to help too:
if (theMagic!=null){
      theMagic.dispose();
     }

Comment: actually  on **line  44** it is disposing Class1 object ..and giving error because Class1 object is not created successfully , root cause is same that Class1 not found.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getProxyLibraryDir(MCRConfiguration.java:270)
 at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$MCRRoot.get(MCRConfiguration.java:71)
 at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$MCRRoot.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:81)    **Stack trace is something like dis  .. cant post full stack trace because ow characters limitation in COMMENTS**

Comment: Can you post the source for MWArray and Class1?

Comment: MWArray is inbuild Type .

Comment: Ok, looks like we've resolved the initial issue and you're now having this problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686761/matlab-ja-builder-throws-nullpointerexception-in-mcrconfiguration

(If there are long pieces of text you need to post, I'd suggest editing the question to include them, that way it doesn't run into character limits.)